# UFW blocks most ports until disabled and re-enabled after reboot

Tags: ubuntu, server, firewall, ufw

I have UFW running on my server. When I restart it:

```
$sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
1194/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5550                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8000                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
1194/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
5550 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

When I try to run it however, my ports 8000 and 1194 are currently being blocked.

When I run:

```
$sudo ufw disable
$sudo ufw enable
```

Then the ports are open. When I run status after that, it is the exact same as previously pasted.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find a resolution?

Comment: No, still has the same issue.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to the reminder from @Nicholas. The problem is caused by `iptables-persistent` indeed. However, simply remove `iptables-persistent` is not a good solution as there maybe other rules applied through `iptables`. Thus if `iptables-persistent` is installed, a better way may be to persistent ufw rules using `iptables-persistent`, i.e.,

```
sudo ufw reload
sudo netfilter-persistent save
```

Answer (score 7):

The real solution is to uninstall `iptables-persistent` and its dependency: `sudo apt remove iptables-persistent` and `sudo apt autoremove`.

As per: https://github.com/pivpn/pivpn/issues/414

Comment: I'll check it out if I get some time soon, thanks for the response.

Comment: this works for me in Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 4):

I'm having same issue with my http and https ports that they are blocked by ufw by reboot. After i disable and enable UFW all ports are running from my UFW firewall rules. Same with sudo ufw reload command.

So i create a workaround by my machine and create a system.d service which starts a simple script in /etc/systemd/system/firewall.service.

```
[Unit]
Description=Firewall restart blocking solution.

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/var/scripts/firewall.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then my script is simple

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo ufw reload
```

At least i setup to start my init.d on boot

```
sudo systemctl enable firewall.service
```

Then all my ports works after a reboot fine. It's maybee a workaround of this issue.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with ufw after a restart of my server. I implemented the service suggested above and that works for me, but I would like to know why ufw is behaving like it does as that doesn't seem to be how ufw is supposed to work.

Answer (score 2):

My impression is that the changes made with ufw have not been saved and are transient. Rebooting without saving the new rules results in loading the previously saved older rules.

Save the new rules with:

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules
```

These rules should be reloaded automatically by the system at boot time. Or they can be reloaded with:

```
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
```